# How to get the Chid Layout's children?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I try to get all the WebView elements in current activity at the time loading and i get the output.
It's working perfectly.

Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.dmp_webview.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

       <WebView
            android:id="@+id/simpleWebView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

       <WebView
            android:id="@+id/simpleWebView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
private void forWebviews() {

    final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
            .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);

    int elementSize = getWenViews(viewGroup).size();
    for(int j =0; j< elementSize;j++)
    {           
        WebView getAllWebView = formIsValid(viewGroup).get(j);
        String SplitTypeWebView = String.valueOf(getAllWebView);
        String getWebValues = getAllWebView.getUrl().toString();
        SplitWebViewID(SplitTypeWebView);
     }  
}

    private ArrayList<WebView> getWenViews(ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ArrayList<WebView> webview = new ArrayList<WebView>();
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof WebView) {
                webview.add((WebView) v);
            }
        }
        return webview;
    }
```

BUT when i one more LinearLayout(Not only linearlayout other layouts also) for webview parent means like this,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.dmp_webview.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/RootLayout_1">

           <WebView
                android:id="@+id/simpleWebView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:scrollbars="none" />

           <WebView
                android:id="@+id/simpleWebView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:scrollbars="none" />

     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Its not working properly. why? It will return no child view counts. I need to clarifying one things.

- is it possible to get the all the child layout's child.
  (e.g )
     **ROOT LAYOUT -> LinearLayout(some other layout)->LinearLayout(some other layout)-Views**

plz guide me.Actually i get root layout and iterate over.
How to get all child views at run time? It does not matter How many root layouts or child layouts or views. i need to get all.

Comment: The `ViewGroup#getChild*()` methods only deal with direct child `View`s, so you're not getting those `WebView`s in nested `ViewGroup`s. In `getWenViews()`, that `if` needs an `else if` for the case that the child is another `ViewGroup` – `else if (v instanceof ViewGroup) { webview.addAll(getWenViews((ViewGroup) v)); }`

Comment: Are you trying to get all the `WebView`s in the layout or all the `WebView`s inside a specific `ViewGroup` ?

Comment: @MikeM. yes mike you are right , it will get the direct child view only, as  per logic i need to add else if to check the other viewgroup.i will try and update to you

Comment: @Titus  need to get all views(does not matter viewgroup/webview if possible means need both of them also)

Comment: Thansks man @MikeM. i forgat about `getAll()` .

Answer (score 0):

> need to get all views(does not matter viewgroup/webview if possible means need both of them also)

You can use a recursive method for that.

Here is an example:

```
private static void getViews(list, ViewGroup viewGroup){
    for(int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++){
        View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        list.add(view);
        if(view instanceof ViewGroup){
            getViews((ViewGroup) view);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how you call it.

```
List<View> list = new ArrayList<View>();
getViews(list, (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(android.R.id.content));
```

And if you want to filter the `WebView`s you can do something like this:

```
List<WebView> webViews = new ArrayList<WebView>();
for(View view : list){
    if(view instanceof WebView){
        webViews.add((WebView) view);
    }
}
```